# Integration of Load Runner in ADO

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, loadrunner

Can anyone please guide me the steps how to integrate Load Runner in Azure DevOps pipeline ?
how to establish a connection between the Load runner and ADO ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to give you some resources in order to help you on your way. I don't have an extensive guide nor do I have the time to create one. But there are certaine things you might want to research and I can give you some tips on creating such a scenario:

**1) You want to setup the preconditions for such a framework:**

- I would recommend using a dedicated Agent on a machine like an Azure VM (Install the DevOps Pipeline Agent on the Azure VM)
- Install LoadRunner on the Agent with the Controller
- Create an Azure Repo with the LoadRunner .XML
- Create a Pipeline with a .yml and select your Repo

**2) Create a Pipeline where you use CmdLine@2 to start your LoadRunner script**

Micro Focus has extensive documentation about running a scenario using the CLI tool. You can integrate such a **LoadRunner CLI command** into the **CmdLine@2** of the Azure DevOps Pipeline.

- [LoadRunner CLI tool documentation](https://admhelp.microfocus.com/lr/en/2022-2022-r2/help/WebHelp/Content/Controller/scenario-run-cli.htm?tocpath=Controller%7CRun%20load%20test%20scenarios%7CRun%20scenarios%20from%20the%20command%20line%7C_____1)
- [DevOps Pipeline CmdLine@2 documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/cmd-line-v2?view=azure-pipelines)

The Pipeline then should have the following elements:

```
trigger:
- none

pool:
  name: '[POOL CONTAINING AGENT]'
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

- task: CmdLine@2
  displayName: 'Task 1: Run LoadRunner Scenario'
  inputs:
    script: <LoadRunner Professional root>\bin\CLIControllerApp.exe -InputFile C:\CLI.xml -CollateAndAnalyze -ResultName C:\ControllerResultPath\Res_01
```

**Additional Documentation**
There are a lot of things you can configure in this situation. I do think this is a sort of make-do setup. I see Micro Focus also has some documentation about  LoadRunner Enterprise and DevOps via [this link](https://admhelp.microfocus.com/lre/en/2022-2022-r2/online_help/Content/PC/Microsoft-Team-Foundation-Plugin.htm).